# What is LinearLayoutCompat in appCompat v7?

Tags: android, android-compatibility

In the support library appCompat v7 of the Android platform, there is a [android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat.html) class.

Does someone know why this class exist? The original LinearLayout class exist since API level 1 so I don't understand why there is a compat version.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The class `LinearLayout` exists since API level 1, but some APIs were added after that, for example, `setShowDividers` introduced on API level 11.

So in this case `setShowDividers` (and it's parameters) should be invoked using `LinearLayoutCompat` instead `LinearLayout` if you are targeting a platform with API level below 11.

Comment: I am confused. If target sdk level is 10. Why should the app use APIs that is in sdk 11?

Comment: @WeishiZeng the target will usually be higher, but the if you choose to include old devices with minSdk < 11, you need the AppCompat Version so that the old devices understand the new parameters as well.

Comment: generally, as of now we always set target higher so i think no need to use `LinearLayoutCompat`

Comment: @Anand Savjani there are many new features added in new apis for example getGravity added in API level 24. If you want to use getGravity and your application's min api version lower then 24 you have to use LinearLayoutCompat. 
You can find methods with their api versions at the following link. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout?hl=en