# Difference between LinearLayout and LinearLayoutcompat, android

Tags: android-layout

I would like to know, What is the difference between android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat and LinearLayout??

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513244/what-is-linearlayoutcompat-in-appcompat-v7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is LinearLayoutCompat in appCompat v7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513244/what-is-linearlayoutcompat-in-appcompat-v7)